# Calling a different method instead in 'execute' in Struts 1.2

Tags: java, struts

In struts 1.2, when an URL in the form http://foo.com/barAction.do is invoked, this will call the `execute` method (or `process`) in the action class that was mapped to *barAction*.

Is it possible to call a different method other than the `execute` (or `process`) in the same action class when the above URL is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [DispatchAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/DispatchAction.html). Basically they allow you to choose which method will be invoked based on a request parameter or action mapping configuration

There are at least 3 "flavours" of DispatchAction: EventDispatchAction, LookupDispatchAction, and MappingDispatchAction.

I'd recommend you to take a lookt at [EventDispatchAction](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-extras/apidocs/org/apache/struts/actions/EventDispatchAction.html) that was introduced in Struts 1.2.9.